# How define a list in Qute template?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

Quarkus version: 3.7.4
I'm trying to define a list of String in a Qute template, something like:

`{#let fruits=java.util.Arrays.listOf("Apple", "Orange", "Lime" /}`

Is there a way to define a List in Qute template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box, i.e. you can't instantiate a new list in the template.

However, you could use [a custom template extension method](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#template_extension_methods) like:

```
import java.util.List;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateExtension;

@TemplateExtension(namespace = "list")
public class ListExtensions {

   static List<String> of(String... elements) {
      return List.of(elements);
   }
}
```

and in the template `{#let fruits=list:of("Apple","Orange","Lime")}..use fruits here..{/}`.

You can also [access static methods](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#accessing-static-fields-and-methods) direcly in a template.